# Rgb to grayscale conversion with arm neon

Tags: assembly, arm, computer-vision, neon

I´m trying to convert from rgb to grayscale efficiently, so I got a function from [here](http://computer-vision-talks.com/2011/02/a-very-fast-bgra-to-grayscale-conversion-on-iphone/) where it explains how to convert from rgba to grayscale. Now I´m trying to do the same but with just rgb. I changed some things but it doesn´t seem to work well. I don´t know why, does anyone see my mistake?

```
void neon_asm_convert(uint8_t * __restrict dest, uint8_t * __restrict src, int numPixels)
{
    __asm__ volatile(
     "lsr %2, %2, #3 \n"
     "# build the three constants:  \n"
     "mov r4, #28                   \n" // Blue channel multiplier
     "mov r5, #151                  \n" // Green channel multiplier
     "mov r6, #77                   \n" // Red channel multiplier
     "vdup.8 d4, r4                 \n"
     "vdup.8 d5, r5                 \n"
     "vdup.8 d6, r6                 \n"
     "0: \n"
     "# load 8 pixels: \n"  //RGBR
     "vld4.8 {d0-d3}, [%1]! \n"
     "# do the weight average: \n"
     "vmull.u8 q7, d0, d4 \n"
     "vmlal.u8 q7, d1, d5 \n"
     "vmlal.u8 q7, d2, d6 \n"
     "# shift and store: \n"
     "vshrn.u16 d7, q7, #8 \n" // Divide q3 by 256 and store in the d7
     "vst1.8 {d7}, [%0]! \n"
     "subs %2, %2, #1 \n" // Decrement iteration count

     "# load 8 pixels: \n"
     "vld4.8 {d8-d11}, [%1]! \n" //Other GBRG
     "# do the weight average: \n"
     "vmull.u8 q7, d3, d4 \n"
     "vmlal.u8 q7, d8, d5 \n"
     "vmlal.u8 q7, d9, d6 \n"
     "# shift and store: \n"
     "vshrn.u16 d7, q7, #8 \n" // Divide q3 by 256 and store in the d7
     "vst1.8 {d7}, [%0]! \n"
     "subs %2, %2, #1 \n" // Decrement iteration count

     "# load 8 pixels: \n"
     "vld4.8 {d0-d3}, [%1]! \n"
     "# do the weight average: \n"
     "vmull.u8 q7, d10, d4 \n"
     "vmlal.u8 q7, d11, d5 \n"
     "vmlal.u8 q7, d0, d6 \n"
     "# shift and store: \n"
     "vshrn.u16 d7, q7, #8 \n" // Divide q3 by 256 and store in the d7
     "vst1.8 {d7}, [%0]! \n"
     "subs %2, %2, #1 \n" // Decrement iteration count


     "# do the weight average: \n"
     "vmull.u8 q7, d1, d4 \n"
     "vmlal.u8 q7, d2, d5 \n"
     "vmlal.u8 q7, d3, d6 \n"
     "# shift and store: \n"
     "vshrn.u16 d7, q7, #8 \n" // Divide q3 by 256 and store in the d7
     "vst1.8 {d7}, [%0]! \n"

     "subs %2, %2, #1 \n" // Decrement iteration count



     "bne 0b \n" // Repeat unil iteration count is not zero
     :
     : "r"(dest), "r"(src), "r"(numPixels)
     : "r4", "r5", "r6"
    );
}
```

Comment: The image is not good transformed.

Comment: Screenshots or anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You load four values (RGBA) instead of 3 (RGB).

you have `RGB RGB RGB` in your image, but you load `RGBR GBRG B...` etc in consecutive steps.

```
"vld4.8 {d0-d3}, [%1]! \n"
```

Instead you should

```
"vld3.8 {d0-d2}, [%1]! \n"
```

Note that I have no idea if my `asm` is correct, but here is the mistake.
Also check for the same mistake when moving the pixels back to memory

Comment: I already took into account that, I´m getting four times the vector from the source, so then I´m able to convert in multiples. I getting RGBR / GBRG /BRGB  an transforming this every time

Comment: What you are doing is to load RGBR, convert RGB to grayscale and ignore second R, then load  GBRB, process GBR as RGB (wrong!), ignore last B, and again... So, you are ignoring some pixels, and load the wrong channels each step.

Answer (score 2):

You should use `"vld3.8 {d0-d2}, [%1]! \n"`

See also http://hilbert-space.de/?p=22

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 1):

Vasile is right. Use VLD3 to load 24bit pixels.

You also have 3 VLDx for 4 VSTx
In fact your code is quite strange...

You don't have to duplicate the code. That's quite complexe to explain but you'll have no interest with NEON to repeat 4 times your code

```
void neon_asm_convert(uint8_t * __restrict dest, uint8_t * __restrict src, int numPixels)
{
  __asm__ volatile(
   "# build the three constants:  \n"
   "mov r4, #28                   \n" // Blue channel multiplier
   "mov r5, #151                  \n" // Green channel multiplier
   "mov r6, #77                   \n" // Red channel multiplier
   "vdup.8 d4, r4                 \n"
   "vdup.8 d5, r5                 \n"
   "vdup.8 d6, r6                 \n"

   "0: \n"
   "# load 8 pixels: \n"  //RGBR
   "vld3.8 {d0-d2}, [%1]! \n"
   "# do the weight average: \n"
   "vmull.u8 q7, d0, d4 \n"
   "vmlal.u8 q7, d1, d5 \n"
   "vmlal.u8 q7, d2, d6 \n"
   "# shift and store: \n"
   "vshrn.u16 d7, q7, #8 \n" // Divide q3 by 256 and store in the d7
   "vst1.8 {d7}, [%0]! \n"
   "subs %2, %2, #1 \n" // Decrement iteration count
   "bne 0b \n" // Repeat unil iteration count is not zero
   :
   : "r"(dest), "r"(src), "r"(numPixels)
   : "r4", "r5", "r6"
  );
}
```

Should works.

Comment: It looks good but It is giving me a memory access error, also I think you forget this a line at the beginning of the function : "lsr %2, %2, #3 \n"

Comment: yes that's correct or replace subs %2, %2, #1 by subs %2, %2, #8